# AWS Layer: adding "/opt/" path when using a Nodejs layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

So I uploaded this layer to AWS using the Serverless framework:

```
service: webstorm-layer

 provider:
   name: aws
   runtime: nodejs8.10
   region: us-east-1

layers:
  nodejs:
   path: nodejs                    # path to contents on disk
   name: node-webstormlibs         # optional, Deployed Lambda layer name
   description: JS shared libs for node
   compatibleRuntimes:
     - nodejs8.10
   allowedAccounts:
     - '*'
```

The libraries I need are inside the "nodejs" directory, there lays my packages.json file and all the "node_modules" directories. So far all looks fine, but when I try to run a lambda that uses the "node-webstormlibs" layer, I'm getting the message:

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'pg'",
```

The pg module actually exists in the zip file that creates the layer. Then, I have doubts about how to import a module that is inside the layer. In some tutorials I see:

```
import pg from "pg";
```

like always, but in other I see:

```
 import pg from "/opt/pg";
```

or even:

```
 import pg from "/opt/nodejs/node_modules/pg";
```

I don't know if the "path:" option in my serverless.yml is correct though.

In the server the path is:

```
NODE_PATH=/opt/nodejs/node8/node_modules/:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR/node_modules
```

**UPDATE**

Putting all in the dir /nodejs/node8, made the trick.

Comment: You are allowed (and encouraged) to add an answer to your own question if you solve it yourself.

Comment: I have the same issue  , i even read every file from the opt directory and i see my files come up but it keeps giving me module not found